# Arithmetic progressions of permutations

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations, arithmetic-progressions

I can't find this question asked anywhere else, however that may be because arithmetic progressions *within* permutations are an existing object of study that seemed to be returned in all my searches. What I want is the opposite: an arithmetic progression whose terms are permutations of the digits of each other, for instance:

$$560, 605, 650$$

are in arithmetic progression, and are all formed by the 'concatenation of a permutation' of the digit set $\{0,5,6\}$.

More precisely, I'd like to define an **arithmetic permutation progression (APP) of degree $n$ and length $m$ in base $\beta$** as a sequence $(a_i)_{i=1}^{m}$ where $a_{i+1}=a_i+k$ for $1\leq i < m$ and $a_1=N$ for some $N, k \in\mathbb{N}$, and if $N$ has base $\beta$ representation $(d_nd_{n-1}\cdots d_2d_1)_\beta$ then each $a_i=(d_{\sigma_i(n)}d_{\sigma_i(n-1)}\cdots d_{\sigma_i(2)}d_{\sigma_i(1)})_\beta$ for some permutation $\sigma_i\in S_n$.

When $m=1,2$, any singleton or pair of numbers is trivially in arithmetic progression, and so any distinct permutations form an APP. The first 'interetsing' case is $m=3$. Note that to have any APPs we need $n!\geq m$, so take $n=m=3$

I wrote some fairly crude python to find all the solutions in this case. There are $14$ sequences for $\beta=10$, but the common difference $k$ only obtains two values: $k=45$ and $k= 333$. Indeed, it seemed that $k$ only obtained at most two values in any base, and more often than not, only one.

So I did some investigation, and after several pages of algebra and consideration of many cases and sub-cases, I reached the following conclusion:

- If $\beta$ is even, then there are $\beta-2$ APPs with $k=\frac12\beta(\beta-1)$,
- If $\beta$ is odd, then there are $\beta-1$ APPs with $k=\frac12(\beta^2-1)$,
- If $\beta \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ then there are $\frac23(\beta-1)$ APPs with $k=\frac13(\beta^3-1)$.

However, I hope that there is a more elegant and concise argument than mine, which might be more condusive to the extension to the case $n=m=4$ and beyond, e.g: is there an 'obvious' reason that $45$ and $333$ are the only possible values of $k$ in base $10$? What conclusions can be drawn for $n=m=4$? Can a general argument be made?

*More Observations:*

- The digit sum of the terms of an APP are clearly all the same.
- For $n=m=3$, the [digit sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum) of $k$ is always $\beta-1$, i.e: $k$ is a mutliple of $\beta-1$.
- It would appear $\beta-1|k$ for $(n,m)=(4,3),(4,4)$ too.
- For $\beta=10$: $n=3$ has APPs with $k_3=45=9\cdot5$, $n=4$ has APPs with $k_4=495=9\cdot55$. If this pattern continues, do we have APPs in even base $\beta$ with $k_n=\frac12\beta(\beta^{n-2}-1)$? Unfortunately, my code isn't good enough to handle $n,m\geq5$.